# Running Query in Lotus Notes/Domino without Showing Notes UI

Tags: c++, com, lotus-notes

I'm writing a small app to display tasks and upcoming calendar items as a Desktop gadget; the information lives on a Domino server, and can be accessed via Notes.

Currently I use COM from C++ to access the database; what is really annoying though is that the Notes UI pops up when I instantiate either `Notes.NotesSession` or `Notes.NotesUIWorkspace`.

Is there a way to avoid this, or is there a better/saner way to access database and calendar information than the Notes Automation library?

Comment: How about via http? You could create an rss/xml compatible view of the calendar you're interested in (since it's server side). I can provide sample code if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sets of classes registered by Notes.  There are OLE classes, which are registered as "Lotus Notes Automation Classes", and there are pure COM classes registered as "Lotus Domino Objects".  If you don't want the UI to come up, you want to be using the latter.

The purpose of the OLE classes is to bring up the Notes client UI and drive it.  Those classes include the NotesUIWorkspace and other "front-end" classes", all of which have "UI" in the name.  There are also back-end classes included in the package for working on saved data without driving the UI.

The COM classes just include the back-end functionality.

Comment: That sounds promising, but [doesn't quite work for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213618/lotus-notes-automation-notes-notessession-doesnt-implement-dominoisession), alas.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly it, but I *think* you need to check the security setting "do not prompt for password from other notes-based programs".  That should prevent the UI from popping up and prompting you to login.

Comment: Not quite -- it's the main app appearing. I don't need to log in explicitly.