# Lotus Notes Automation: Notes.NotesSession doesn't implement Domino::ISession?

Tags: c++, com, lotus-notes

I'm trying to improve my Lotus Notes client code:

Working:

```
#import "...\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes32.tlb" no_dual_interfaces raw_native_types

CComPtr<IDispatch> session_dispatch;
if(FAILED(session_dispatch.CoCreateInstance(_T("Notes.NotesSession"))))
    ...
NOTESSESSION *session = static_cast<NOTESSESSION *>(*&session_dispatch);
```

This gives me a valid `NOTESSESSION` object that is aware that it needs to go through `IDispatch` to actually invoke methods.

I found some [example code](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=635485) on the net, which looks a lot saner and assumes a later Notes version:

```
#import "...\IBM\Lotus\Notes\domobj.tlb" raw_interfaces_only raw_native_types

CComPtr<Domino::ISession> notes;
if(FAILED(notes.CoCreateInstance(_T("Notes.NotesSession"))))
    ...
```

However that returns `E_NOINTERFACE`. As others claim to have similar code working, I wonder what may be going on here, and humbly ask whether anyone else has working code to instantiate a Session object and get a working interface pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With domobj.tlb, you should use "Domino.NotesSession" rather than "Notes.NotesSession".

Comment: Hm, that one doesn't exist in my registry. [This page](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21112239) suggests that the COM library is often not registered properly.

Comment: Yep, that worked. \o/ Accepting your answer as it put me on the right track, even though the original name appears to be correct.

Comment: Yes, there have been registration problems in some Lotus Notes versions in the past.  It's also possible that they changed the name in the past, as well.  

In my current dev environment, with Notes 8.5.3, the class name is definitely Domino.NotesSession -- but I'm working in C# and there's the interop layer interceding.  I suppose that might be changing the name.

I just looked at the Domino Designer documentation for 8.5.3, and it actually says that the name should be Lotus.NotesSession for the COM classes in domobj.tlb, and Notes.NotesSession for the OLE classes in Notes32.tlb.

Comment: Well, it works fine now, thanks lots! Making a proper package from this program is going to be a nightmare as I should probably fix the component registration in the installer.

Comment: Fixing it your installer might not be wise.  There can be multiple Notes/Domino installs on a machine, with no way other than asking the user to determine which one to use , and a lot of users will not know.  If you end up going against the wrong version of Notes, it could turn into one of those horrible support issues where everything "looks right" but just doesn't work.  I would probably recommend just detecting the issue, and putting up a dialog box informing the user to call their helpdesk and referring them to this IBM technote: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21112239